# c# thread safety socket confusion

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have what I believe to be a thread safety issue.

I have two printers, one is loaded with a small label and the other a large. I want to send 1 print job over a socket to *each* printer.

I have attempted to thread/background the first request (large label) as it can take a long time to complete.

99% of the time the script works as expected. The small and big labels come out of their respective printers.

However, every now and then both the big and small labels are sent to the same printer! Either both to the small or large.

I think it's related to thread safety but I am finding it very hard to track down and understand whats happening. I've tried to add a lock and to close the sockets after use, but whatever I try the issue persists.

I've attempted to reduce my code to the bare minimum but am aware this post is still very code heavy. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
// stores the printer info
class PrinterBench
{
    public PrinterBench(string sArg_PostageLabelIP, string sArg_SmallLabelIP)
    {
        PostageLabelIP = sArg_PostageLabelIP;
        SmallLabelIP = sArg_SmallLabelIP;
    }
    public string PostageLabelIP;
    public string SmallLabelIP;
}

// main entry point
class HomeController{

    PrintController oPrintController;
    List<string> lsLabelResults = new List<string>("label result");
    PrinterBench pbBench        = new PrinterBench("192.168.2.20","192.168.2.21");

    void Process(){

        oPrintController = new PrintController(this);

        if(GetLabel()){
            // should always come out of the big printer (runs in background)
            oPrintController.PrintBySocketThreaded(lsLabelResults, pbBench.PostageLabelIP);
            // should always come out of the small printer
            oPrintController.PrintWarningLabel();
        }
    }
}


class PrintController{

    HomeController oHC;
    public EndPoint ep { get; set; }
    public Socket sock { get; set; }
    public NetworkStream ns { get; set; }

    private static Dictionary<string, Socket> lSocks = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();

    private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;
    static readonly object locker = new object();
    double dProgress;
    bool bPrintSuccess = true;

    public PrintController(HomeController oArg_HC)
    {
        oHC = oArg_HC;
    }

    public bool InitSocks()
    {
        // Ensure the IP's / endpoints of users printers are assigned
        if (!lSocks.ContainsKey(oHC.pbBench.PostageLabelIP))
        {
            lSocks.Add(oHC.pbBench.PostageLabelIP, null);
        }
        if (!lSocks.ContainsKey(oHC.pbBench.SmallLabelIP))
        {
            lSocks.Add(oHC.pbBench.SmallLabelIP, null);
        }

        // attempt to create a connection to each socket
        foreach (string sKey in lSocks.Keys.ToList())
        {
            if (lSocks[sKey] == null || !lSocks[sKey].Connected )
            {
                ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sKey), 9100);
                lSocks[sKey] = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                lSocks[sKey].Connect(ep);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public bool PrintBySocketThreaded(List<string> lsToPrint, string sIP)
    {
        // open both the sockets
        InitSocks();

        bBatchPrintSuccess = false;
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        object[] parameters = new object[] { lsToPrint, sIP, lSocks };

        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
        return true;
    }


    // On worker thread, send to print!
    public void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] parameters = e.Argument as object[];

        double dProgressChunks = (100 / ((List<string>)parameters[0]).Count);
        int iPos = 1;

        Dictionary<string, Socket> dctSocks = (Dictionary<string, Socket>)parameters[2];

        foreach (string sLabel in (List<string>)parameters[0] )
        {
            bool bPrinted = false;

            // thread lock print by socket to ensure its not accessed twice
            lock (locker)
            {
                // get relevant socket from main thread
                bPrinted = PrintBySocket(sLabel, (string)parameters[1], dctSocks[(string)parameters[1]]);
            }

            iPos++;
        }

        while (!((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
        {
            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancelAsync();
            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).Dispose();
            //Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        return;
    }


    // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar (have access to main thread data)!
    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        if (bPrintSuccess) oHC.WriteLog("Printing Complete");

        bBatchPrintSuccess = true;

        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancelAsync();
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).Dispose();
    }

    /// sends to printer via socket
    public bool PrintBySocket(string sArg_ToPrint, string sIP, Socket sock = null)
    {
        Socket sTmpSock = sock;

        if (sTmpSock == null)
        { 
            InitSocks();

            if (!lSocks.ContainsKey(sIP)){
                throw new Exception("Sock not init");
            }else{
                sTmpSock = lSocks[sIP];
            }
        }

        using (ns = new NetworkStream(sTmpSock))
        {
            byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sEOL + sArg_ToPrint);
            ns.BeginWrite(toSend, 0, toSend.Length, OnWriteComplete, null);
            ns.Flush();
        }
        return true;
    }


    public bool PrintWarningLabel()
    {
        string sOut = sEOL + "N" + sEOL;
        sOut += "LL411" + sEOL;
        sOut += "R40,0" + sEOL;
        sOut += "S5" + sEOL;
        sOut += "D15" + sEOL;
        sOut += "A0,0,0,4,4,3,N,\"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\"" + sEOL;
        sOut += "A0,150,0,4,3,3,N,\"WARNING MESSAGE TO PRINT\"" + sEOL;
        sOut += "A0,280,0,4,4,3,N,\"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\"" + sEOL;
        sOut += "P1";
        sOut += sEOL;

        if (PrintBySocket(sOut, oHC.pbBench.SmallLabelIP))
        {
            oHC.WriteLog("WARNING LABEL PRINTED");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this field in `PrintController`:

```
public NetworkStream ns { get; set; }
```

It's only used here:

```
    using (ns = new NetworkStream(sTmpSock))
    {
        byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sEOL + sArg_ToPrint);
        ns.BeginWrite(toSend, 0, toSend.Length, OnWriteComplete, null);
        ns.Flush();
    }
```

If two threads execute this at the same time, one can change `ns` to a different `NetworkStream` when the other is about to write to it.

Since `ns` is used and disposed right here, there doesn't seem to be any reason to declare it as a field, which means multiple threads can overwrite it. Instead, delete the field and change your code to this:

```
using (var ns = new NetworkStream(sTmpSock))
```

Then multiple threads executing this will create their own `NetworkStream` as a local variable instead of fighting over one.

I'd check all the other fields too and see if they need to be fields or if they can just be declared as local variables.

Unintentional shared state is bad for multithreaded code. It will behave exactly as you described. It works, it works, it works, and then it doesn't work, and reproducing the problem when you want to see it will be nearly impossible.

Comment: What a brilliant answer! As you said, it’s been very tricky to diagnose. Many thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I'm having some issues with a socket timing out and hanging the application. Would be greatly appreciated if you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345018/multithreaded-socket-connection-hangs-c-socket-timeout-hangs